# Image with a heading, subheading and button (responsive) how please?

Tags: css

Please help me with some very simple code.
All i want is a background image, on top of it a h1, h2, and a text. Centered and responsive for all devices. Please i am researching for hours, help me out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

please add your CSS.
About background image, set in your css:

```
 background-image: URL('your image URL');
```

for more options, [click on this URL](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp)
about the rest, try position absolute.

Comment: add my css? Excuse me thats exactly what i am asking for. I dont know the css ................

Comment: Try what I write